# How to open mysql workbench tab which are closed without saving by mistake?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Recently, By mistake i closed `mysql workbench` tab in which i have written half stored procedure, and i did not saved it,
 so is there anyway to reopen unsaved closed tab or recover whatever i have written in that tab. your suggestions appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: If by chance you have run the query (even incomplete) 
you should be able to see it in "History output" in ACTION OUTPUT Tab  
or
HELP  >> SHOW LOG FILE

Comment: but i did not run that, so is there anyway i can reopen tab like in chrome `ctrl+shift+T`

Comment: I guess No then.
Theres nothing you can do, if you haven't saved it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You may find your unsaved work in `%appdata%\MySQL\Workbench\sql_workspaces\` or perhaps `%appdata%\MySQL\Workbench\sql_history\`.  I hope this helps!

If you use Mac, you probably will find it in `~/Library/Application Support/MySQL/Workbench/sql_history`.

To get what you really want, you will need to replace somethings like `&quot;` by `"` or `&#x0A;` by `<space>`

Comment: i can't found the exact code, it contain timestamp and other garbage code which i did not write in my stored procedure. also, there is so many files everywhere, so it's hard to find your one.

Comment: To clarify: within the sql_workspaces directory are folders named {connection_name}.autosave that contain a .scratch file per tab, containing the tab's last autosaved contents if you have autosave enabled (which it appears to be by default).

Comment: For ubuntu 20.04 users, snap install, the path to look for is: ~/snap/mysql-workbench-community/<ver>/.mysql/workbench/sql_history/

Comment: I have ubutnu 22.04 and workbench not installed via snap. The location of unsaved scripts is in /home/<user>/.mysql/workbench/sql_workspaces/<some_workspace>/*.scratch

Answer (score 7):

For window user:

1. Go to location to get the log file:
   C:\Users{userName}\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\log
   If the file is not present in above location then follow below steps:
   a. Open your workbench.
   b. go to help->Show log file
   c. Find the variable name: "APPDATA". You will get the location of Mysql file
   e. Open the path. Then inside that go to "\MySQL\Workbench\log"
2. Sort the logs based on date.
3. Open the first one. It contains all the executed commands.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Workbench regularly saves open editors (if the associated option is set in the preferences) and when you reopen your connection it will bring back all the editors and their content. However, this does not happen for all editors you ever had open. Once you close an editor (before closing the connection) there is no trace left of its content, unless you were editing a file, in which case the original file still exists of course.